# Redirection not working - Facebook

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, redirect

I've got the following Problem.

I got a domain which I use for tracking and redirecting after that to my Maindomain.

The problem is that it seems that most of the requests ignore the redirect.

Whatever I try, window.location manipulation, $.ajax, http-equiv: Refresh Meta-Tags or HTTP Location Header.

The server is logging a lot of requests to the original url (see code example) but the second request to the destination url is only send very rarely.

Most of the affected request come from the Facebook InApp Browser. 95% of the requests are not sending the second request.

If I and a few other people tried to click on those urls in facebook, we got redirected correctly. Sadly we can not reproduce it which is why I want to ask for help here.

Does anyone has experience with such an issue? The Facebook InApp Browser seems to only sometimes execute javascript.

Original url: http://track.com/cG45ciD4

This is my redirection code I used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = {
    "url": "http://www.example.com"
};
try {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        try {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/track/cG45ciD4",
                cache: false,
                data: d,
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(data);
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus);
            }).always(function() {
                window.location.replace(d['url']);
             });
            } catch(e) { window.location.replace(d['url']); }
        });
    } catch(e) { window.location.replace(d['url']); }
</script>
```

Comment: Related issue? -> http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84388/javascript-in-facebooks-in-app-browser

Comment: Can you try to change `window.location.replace(d['url'])` with `window.location = d['url']` and update it if works?

Comment: Tried it, it is still not working.